# How to use hibernate in a ready java project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Recently i have made a simple database project with the help of jsp and servlet. I have done lot of the work in the jsp layouts and servelt. It has around 30 jsp files. But due to lot of repeated code for the connectivity files to database it has been very complex. I want to reduce this complexity by managing the code.

I've heard about Hibernate framework which is used for database connectivity for make the project simple and unrepeated code. Now i want to convert this same project with hibernate. Is it possible? And where from i should need to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible, however, what seems to be the issue is this:

> I have done lot of the work in the jsp layouts and servlet.

You also mention that you have a lot of repeated code.

You would probably need to consider to encapsulate the database operations and move them from the JSP pages (if I am understanding your point correctly) to appropriate bean classes. You would then call these beans from your JSP pages. This should reduce code duplication, thus making your application more maintainable.

After this refactoring process, you can proceed and implement the Hibernate framework within your system.